# How can i call onload() function in the javascript file without ruining the code?

Tags: javascript, html, onload

i have a tic-tac-toe code, that when i call the "onload()" function in the html  tag, the code works perfect, but when i use it as i use it down below, in the javascript file, the first game is not working correctly (its like the first move is not defined).

this is the html code:

```
<html>
    <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="gamestyle.css">
        <script src="gamescript.js"></script>
    </head>
<body>
<div class="table">
    <h1>Tic-Tac-Toe Game</h1>
    <div id = "message">messages will go here</div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col" onclick="nextMove(this);" id="s1">
        </div>
        <div class="col" id="s2" onclick="nextMove(this);">
        </div>
        <div id="s3" class="col" onclick="nextMove(this);">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div id="s4" class="col" onclick="nextMove(this);">
        </div>
        <div id="s5" class="col" onclick="nextMove(this);">
        </div>
        <div id="s6" class="col" onclick="nextMove(this);">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div id="s7" class="col" onclick="nextMove(this);">
        </div>
        <div id="s8" class="col" onclick="nextMove(this);">
        </div>
        <div id="s9" class="col" onclick="nextMove(this);">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<a href="javascript:startGame();">Start Over</a>

</body>
</html>
```

and this is the javascript code:

```
var winner
var turn
var counter;
function startGame() {
    for(var i = 1; i <= 9; i = i + 1){
        clearBox(i);
        document.getElementById("s" + i).style.backgroundColor = "blue";
    }
    counter = 0;


    turn = "X";
    if(Math.random() < 0.5){
        turn = "O";
    }
    winner = undefined;
    setMessage(turn + " gets to start.");

}

function setMessage(msg){
    document.getElementById("message").innerText = msg;
}

function nextMove(square){
    if(winner != undefined){
        setMessage(winner + " already won the game.");
    } else if (square.innerText != "X" && square.innerText != "O") {
        square.innerText = turn;
        switchTurn(square);
    }
    else{
    setMessage("That square is already used, " + turn + "'s turn again.");
    }
}

function switchTurn(square){
    if(checkForWinner(turn) || counter == 9){
        winner = turn;
        if (counter == 9 && checkForWinner(turn) == false)
        {
            square.innerText = turn;
            alert("Its a tie!");
        }
        else
        {
            alert("Congratulations " + turn + "! you win!");
        }
    }else if(turn == "X"){
    turn = "O";
    setMessage("It's " + turn + "'s turn");
    }
    else{
    turn = "X";
    setMessage("It's " + turn + "'s turn");
    }

}

function checkForWinner(move){
    var result = false;
    counter++;
    if(checkRow(1, 2, 3, move)){
        result = true;
        PaintWinning(1, 2, 3);
    }
    if(checkRow(4, 5, 6, move)){
        result = true;
        PaintWinning(4,5,6);
    }
    if(checkRow(7, 8, 9, move)){
        result = true;
        PaintWinning(7,8,9);
    }
    if(checkRow(1, 4, 7, move)){
        result = true;
        PaintWinning(1,4,7);
    }
    if(checkRow(2, 5, 8, move)){
        result = true;
        PaintWinning(2,5,8);
    }
    if(checkRow(3, 6, 9, move)){
        result = true;
        PaintWinning(3,6,9);
    }
    if(checkRow(1, 5, 9, move)){
        result = true;
        PaintWinning(1,5,9);
    }
    if(checkRow(3, 5, 7, move)){
        result = true;
        PaintWinning(3,5,7);
    }
    return result;
}

function checkRow(a,b,c,move){
    var result = false;
    if(getBox(a) == move && getBox(b) == move && getBox(c) == move){
    result = true;
    }
    return result;
}

function getBox(number){
    return document.getElementById("s" + number).innerText;
}

function clearBox(number){
    document.getElementById("s" + number).innerText = "";
}

function PaintWinning(a, c, b) {
    document.getElementById("s" + a).style.backgroundColor = "green";
    document.getElementById("s" + b).style.backgroundColor = "green";
    document.getElementById("s" + c).style.backgroundColor = "green";
}
object.addEventListener("load", startGame());
```

i want to put the onload() function in the javascript file instead of the html file, but as i tried it doesn't work very well

Comment: Change `object` to `document`.

Comment: if onload event is causing errors you can add something like this on the JS File: document.addEventListener("load", NAMEOFYOURFUNCTION()); and delete "onload" function of your html code

Comment: Given the above code, what is currently happening, and what exactly do you want to happen? "does not work very well" is very vague. Be concise in what you want

Comment: ive did that on my javascript file @Joanmi and i changed the object to document, but that still does not working. my first click on a div tag shows "undefined" and not an 'X'\'O'

Comment: Remove the () from startGame(), and I believe (could be wrong) that you need to add the event to the body itself, so it should read:
document.body.addEventListener("load", startGame);